# EventQueue.invokeLater vs Thread.start

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

For Swing applications, is there a reason we use `EventQueue.invokeLater()`?  Should't `Thread.start()` work the same way?

Another advantage of Thread.start is we have a way of telling the thread to interrupt as `EventQueue.invokeLater` does not provide us with the `Thread` object.

Answer (score 3):

You should use EventQueue.invokeLater for all GUI updates since Swing in a way is singlethreaded. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading

You can start threads to do calculations etc, but should update the GUI using invokeLater.

Comment: So if you're not doing any GUI update, but doing "model" update is it fine to use Thread.start or should we still use EventQueue.il?

Comment: @Archimedes Trajano: If your model update would block the GUI for a long period of time, you should update the model in a separate Thread. "Long period of time" is more than 200 milliseconds.

Comment: Nope it's more like setting the status text to "Stopping..." for example.  But it sounds like it is okay to do it that way.

Comment: `So if you're not doing any GUI update, but doing "model" update is it fine to use Thread.start` - no, because a change to the model causes the GUI component to repaint itself.

Comment: @camickr perfectly true for all swing models, and that's how it should be! But they seem to be talking about a "crippled model", that is one which is not notifying any listeners, see Gilbert's example, so might be a borderline case, as long as the controller ensures the update on the EDT

Comment: @camickr So can we do this: Thread.start() for a calculation thread which I can terminate using Thread.interrupt() and then in that thread use Event.invokeLater() to update the model?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, yes, or you can use a SwingWorker which is designed to do this for you. You run the SwingWorker which start a Thread for you and then you can `publish` results and the code will automatically run on the EDT. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the Swing single Threaded rule and the SwingWorker.

Comment: @camickr I see, perhaps you can write up your comments into an answer, I'll mark it as the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Your two options for starting a Swing application are:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater()
```

and

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
```

My preference is to use SwingUtilities.  They both put the runnable on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT).  You don't need a handle to the EDT.

Your code is either on the EDT, or another invocation of the invokeLater() method will put the runnable on the EDT.  You can determine either condition with the SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() method call.

The Thread.start() method is for your own worker threads.  Or, if you wish, you can use the [javax.swing.SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) class for your own Swing worker threads.

Here's the boilerplate that I use to start every Swing application I write.

```
package com.ggl.game2048;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.game2048.model.Game2048Model;
import com.ggl.game2048.view.Game2048Frame;

public class Game2048 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Game2048Frame(new Game2048Model());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Game2048());
    }

}
```

Short and to the point.  This class does 3 things.

1. Puts the Swing application on the EDT.
2. Instantiates the Swing application model.
3. Instantiates the Swing application JFrame.

You can see the rest of the [2048 Swing application](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=516) in my Java article.

Comment: Thanks, that's normally how I do things, but that's not applicable to my question.

Comment: BTW nice implementation of 2048

Comment: @Archimedes Trajano: The answer is not just for you, but for everybody that comes along later and finds this question with a search.

Comment: yet another crippelled (some call it passive, though ;-) Model implementation _A model notifies its associated views and controllers when there has been a change in its state._

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(…)` just delegates to `EventQueue.invokeLater(…)`. Can’t see what backups your preference to use `SwingUtilities`… And by the way you can **not** use the `javax.swing.Timer` class for your “own Swing worker threads”. Swing’s `Timer` just delivers `ActionEvent`s within the EDT.

Comment: @Holger: I fixed my answer to mention javax.swing.SwingWorker instead of javax.swing.Timer.  My mistake, as I've always used Thread.  Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  It's easier for me to remember SwingUtilities over EventQueue.  That's the basis for my preference.